# Media volume either 0% or 100%

Tags: android, android-source

I have a custom android AOSP ROM with a peculiar problem: The volume can only be set to either 0% or 100%. As a result, the volume buttons just turn the sound on or off. If I use the volume slider instead, and the volume is not muted, it jumps immediately to 100%. The volume is not reduced even momentarily.

Interestingly, the volume for ringtones and alarms is not affected and can be set as usual.

The problem occurs via headphones, internal speakers, and HDMI out.

I tried `setprop ro.config.media_vol_steps 30`, and that does work in that it changes the number of volume steps in the slider - but it does not affect the output volume. I found nothing in `logcat`, this is the only suspicious thing (I set the volume via slider to a low value):

```
02-08 06:18:43.117  1813  2298 V audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: routing=1024
02-08 06:18:43.670 22493 22493 I vol.Events: writeEvent touch_level_changed STREAM_MUSIC 3
02-08 06:18:44.127 22493 22493 I vol.Events: writeEvent touch_level_done STREAM_MUSIC 3
02-08 06:18:46.575 22493 22493 I vol.Events: writeEvent dismiss_dialog touch_outside
02-08 06:18:46.581 22493 24066 I vol.Events: writeEvent active_stream_changed UNKNOWN_STREAM_-1
02-08 06:18:46.695  1813  2298 V audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: routing=1024
02-08 06:18:49.842  1813  2298 D audio_hw_primary: out_standby
```

What could cause this? E.g. does the hardware report the current volume back to the UI (then it could be a driver problem)?

Answer (score 0):

In your ROM, a fixed-volume (full) is set. Its a resource configuration. Usually done for HDMI devices.